# Como puedo añadir una firma digital al pdf usando laravel 5.5 laravel-snappy

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pdf, laravel-blade, firma-digital

Estoy usando Laravel 5.5 laravel-snappy para crear PDF.

Querría firmar los PDF digitalmente después de cargar una vista.

No se que hacer. Existe algún componente o plugin para hacerlo ?

Answer (score 1):

Directamente no se puede, pero puedes generar el PDF

```
return PDF::loadFile('http://www.github.com')->inline('github.pdf');
```

y luego usar otra API para firmarla como [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)